# When I use overflow:scroll will be ruined other div tags position in css

Tags: html, css

I have problem about the div tags and overflow attribute in css.

In my code when one of top div tags (in left side of page) disable overflowing the bottom div tags change the position. but when top div tags enable page is without any problem.

Please help me. thanks.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/BaseStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/MediaQuery.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Header"> </div>
    <div class="Content">
      <div class="LoginForm">
        <div>
          <div class="UniLogo">
            <img src="Uni-LOGO.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="SystemName"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iStudentCode" placeholder="نام کاربری">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="iPassword" placeholder="کلمه عبور">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iPassword" placeholder="متن تصویر">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="botdetect3-captcha-sunandwarmair.jpg" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="btnLogin"></button>
        <br />

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">کلمه عبور را فراموش کرده ام</button>
      </div>
      <div class="Bulltin">
        <div class="BulltinTitle">
          <span>تابلوی اعلانات اساتید</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Messages">
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Bulltin">
        <div class="BulltinTitle">
          <span>تابلوی اعلانات آموزش</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Messages">
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Bulltin">
        <div class="BulltinTitle">
          <span>تابلوی اعلانات مالی</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Messages">
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Bulltin">
        <div class="BulltinTitle">
          <span>تابلوی آیین نامه های آموزشی</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Messages">
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="Message">
            <div class="Time">منتشر شده در تاریخ 95/5/5</div>
            <div class="Title">این مکان عنوان پیغام است</div>
            <div>قابل توجه دانشجویان مهندسی نرم افزار این فایل جهت تست می باشد.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="Footer">تمامی حقوق این سامانه متعلق به دانشگاه  مازندران می باشد.</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  direction: rtl;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'DroidNaskh-Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html {
  bottom: 0px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'DroidNaskh-Regular';
}

.Content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 6% auto;
}

.LoginForm {
  width: 33%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0.333333%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.Bulltin {
  width: 29%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 4.333333%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;

  /*display:block;*/
}

.UniLogo {
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  float: right;
}

.UniLogo img {
  width: 100%;
}

.SystemName {
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.BulltinTitle {
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}

.BulltinTitle span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #1a18d3;
  margin: 0;
}
.Messages {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  position:relative;
}

.Message {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position:relative;

}

.Message .Time {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #808080;
}

.Message .Title {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1a4ced;
}

.Header {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #6b6a6a;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #808080;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It looks fine for me in JSBin... I used the same code above.

Comment: Is your browser zoomed in?

Comment: No, my browser is in default size.